# Summary of “Almost All Orbits of the Collatz Map Attain Almost Bounded Values”

Tags: nt.number-theory, soft-question, ds.dynamical-systems, collatz-conjecture

Terence Tao's 2019 [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03562) ``Almost all Orbits of the Collatz map attain almost bounded values" is pretty famous. However, it's also long and complicated. I think there are useful techniques to glean from this paper for expressing an intuitive probabilistic heuristic in a precise and technical way.

Unfortunately, I find reading this particular paper very difficult. Furthermore, his summaries are incredibly vague: ``a certain distribution" or ``a fine-scale mixing property" and so on.

I was hoping someone who understood his proof might be able to provide a detailed but non-technical summary of how he proves his result. What I mean by that is a description, intuitively, of what he's doing. For instance, one could say, ``he uses the total variation metric to bound the change in distribution from successive iterations of the Syracuse map” but not write out the precise definition of what the total variation $d_{TV}(X,Y)$ of two random variables is.

There is a [video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmK1kTrOo7M) online that is rather helpful, but, again, it is very long. And also very slow! I often find myself increasing the playback speed. It also involves many proofs that detract from the overall theme of what's going on.

Comment: I know you intentionally added back the TeX-style quotes, although MathJax does not obey them as quotes, but notice that this disturbs the formatting because MathJax *does* obey them as code-block delimiters:  see “``a certain distribution" or ``a fine-scale mixing property"”.

Comment: I don't notice anything.

Comment: It feels like you are asking for people to do the work of explaining a paper to you. Without more detailed knowledge of what you already know, what you want to know, and your own tastes regarding "intution", "insight", and so forth, it seems hard to supply you on MO with what you want

Comment: @YemonChoi No, it doesn't fell like that. I very clearly stated that I only wanted a brief, intuitive description of how he arrived at his result. Apparently, no one understands the paper enough to do that, and that's perfectly fine.

Comment: @YemonChoi Your comment really bothers me. "Work." I'm not a mathematician. I'm not a student. No one is paying me to read papers. No one is paying me to do anything, actually. How dare I ask for help understanding something, right? God forbid research papers be written in a clear and accessible manner. No one deserves assistance, and those who need it don't deserve to understand in the first place? Is that it?

Comment: @user144527 Nobody is getting paid to answer questions on MO either. Terry Tao isn't getting paid to write his blog, but he does it anyway precisely to help people like you, who aren't experts in this particular field, to understand these new results. Moreover, nobody is saying they won't help you, you just need to be more specific. You are being very ungrateful: a lot of people are trying to help you for free, maybe if you're struggling you need to develop a stronger background before you try to tackle research-level papers.

Comment: @user144527:  Although I share some of your sentiments, I will have to point out to you that mathematics papers are meant to be *terse*.  (That is how it has always been, although I do know that mathematicians aim for greater pedagogy when writing expository papers.)  That being said, I believe it will take some time before a *maximally pedagogical exposition* of Tao's proof is available, given that the ideas he used are *revolutionary*.  (To the moderators:  Is it not the case that the **Be Nice Policy** is also in place for MathOverflow?  I do know that it is in effect in MSE.) ... (cont'd.)

Comment: @user144527: We do have to thank Tao for at least providing *some minimally pedagogical expositions*.  You would have to understand that mathematicians are humans too.  Research is not the only thing they do. They have teaching duties, they need to check exam papers, and some even have administrative responsibilities on top of that.  Harry was not being mean or impolite, Harry was just stating it as a *matter of fact*.

Comment: @user144527:  You might be interested in [this recent expository paper on Tao's proof](https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/17937).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the old reason "no longer relevant"

Answer (score 9):

Since this is a longstanding open problem, the fact that the sources you looked at have long discussions of many technical details is not surprising.

Terry Tao has two blogposts on this topic where he gives an informal description, with additional discussions in the comments.

[Almost all collatz orbits attain almost bounded values](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/09/10/almost-all-collatz-orbits-attain-almost-bounded-values/)

[Equidistribution of Syracuse random variables and density of collatz preimages](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2020/01/25/equidistribution-of-syracuse-random-variables-and-density-of-collatz-preimages/)

**Edit:** In an earlier blogpost Tao has presented some heuristic arguments regarding the same topic. In particular he uses some approximate counting arguments to heuristically bound the number of counterexamples by a quantity that goes to zero under a suitable regime.

[Collatz conjecture Littlewood Offord Theory and powers of 2 and 3](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/the-collatz-conjecture-littlewood-offord-theory-and-powers-of-2-and-3/)

Comment: Yes, I have looked at these before. I would not call them "informal."

Comment: if these are not informal enough for you, then there are some articles in Quanta magazine on Terry Tao's proof, as well as a more recent computational SAT solver approach.

Comment: Maybe what I'm asking for is too much. I can almost read the paper, but I need some prerequisites. I'm trying to determine if what he does could be useful in order to assess whether I should spend the effort to understand what he did. His summaries do not help in this regard, and magazine articles are too vague.

Comment: Just curious, have you actually read the paper?

Comment: Here's an example: He goes from Proposition 1.11 to Theorem 1.6 by partitioning the integers into sets $[x^{j \alpha}, x^{(j+1)\alpha})$ and then using the law of total probability to bound exceptional first passage times. This is a simple, short, intuitive insight. With it, it is very clear what Proposition 1.11 is doing. Without it, all those $x^\alpha$ are a jumbled mess of symbols. Just a small, intuitive insight makes whatever you're looking at very readable when you're not familiar with standard techniques, but these insights are not in magazine articles. Do you get my meaning?